# Dimension reduction methods: overview of complexity

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, matrix-decomposition, time-complexity

For classical dimension reduction methods (PMF, PCA, SVD, t-SNE...) or some others, I need to know the complexity of efficient implementations:

- with $N$ vectors
- in dimension $d$
- reduced to dimension $k$

How do you express the complexity of each (or some) of these methods?

As a special case, the complexity of an implementation for spare vectors (with average nonzero entries $c$) would be appreciated. For example, SVD has complexity $O(dcN)$.

*Note: Some methods may be iterative with $i$ iterations. This is a least concern for scaling since $i$ tends to grow only logarithmically (as far as i know). Maybe you can skip it.*

Comment: You have mentioned K-means. How is K-means used to dimension reduction?

Comment: It is not. It was written in the question. I've switched to SVD to avoid confusing people.

Answer (score 2):

This interesting question should be, in my opinion rephrased, because many of these methods have different implementations that can be used in different contexts (not only sparse vs dense - see [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-dimensionality-reduction.html#performance) for example).

More appropriate question would be: *what is the complexity of **algorithms*** that perform these decompositions.

For basic methods you can see scikit-learn's documentation on following modules:

- [decompositions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#sparsepca) (covers (some) algorithms for PCA, its variants, dictionary learning, Factor Analysis, ICA and NMF)
- [manifold learning](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html) (covers Isomap, LLE, Hessian Eigenmaps, Spectral Embedding, LTSA and t-SNE).

---

### Some remarks:

**Spectral dimensionality** reduction methods (every method mentioned from `manifold` except t-SNE) have the following pipeline:

- calculate nearest neighbors to construct graph on this data (edges correspond to distances to nearest neighbors)
- calculate distance in this graph
- decompose appropriate matrix in some way

That means their complexity depends on at least 3 factors - in `scikit-learn` for example you can specify the kNN method.

**Randomized algorithms** are used by some approximate matrix decomposition methods (this is related to random projections).

From [Finding Structure in Randomness](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4061.pdf) (section 1.4.1. on dense matrices, next section treats sparse matrices):

> (...) standard deterministic technique for computing an approximate SVD is to perform a rank-revealing
>   QR factorization of the matrix, and then to manipulate the factors
>   to obtain the final
>   decomposition. The cost of this approach is typically $O(kmn)$ floating-point operations, or
>   flops
>   , although these methods require slightly longer running times in rare
>   cases.
>
> In contrast, randomized schemes can produce an approximate SVD using only
>   $O(mnlog(k) + (m+n)k^2)$ flops. The gain in asymptotic complexity is achieved by
>   using a random matrix
>   $\Omega$
>   that has some internal structure(...)